# Делаю задачку с codinGame

Tags: c++

Делаю  задание:

> Shadows of the Knight - Episode 1.
>   Задание: Batman will look for the
>   hostages on a given building by jumping from one window to another
>   using his grapnel gun. Batman's goal is to jump to the window where
>   the hostages are located in order to disarm the bombs. Unfortunately
>   he has a limited number of jumps before the bombs go off...   Rules
>
> Before each jump, the heat-signature device will provide Batman with
>   the direction of the bombs based on Batman current position:  U (Up)
>   UR (Up-Right) R (Right) DR (Down-Right) D (Down) DL (Down-Left) L
>   (Left) UL (Up-Left)

Моя часть  кода:

```
while (1) 
{
    string bombDir; // the direction of the bombs from batman's current location (U, UR, R, DR, D, DL, L or UL)
    cin >> bombDir; cin.ignore();


    if ( bombDir == "U")
        array[1][1] = Y0 - 1;
    if( bombDir == "D")
        array[0][1] = Y0 + 1;
    if ( bombDir == "L") 
        array[1][0] = X0 - 1;
    if ( bombDir == "R" ) 
        array[0][0] = X0 + 1;

    X0 = array[0][0] + (array[1][0] - array[0][0]) / 2;
    Y0 = array[0][1] + (array[1][1] - array[0][1]) / 2;   
    // Write an action using cout. DON'T FORGET THE "<< endl"
    // To debug: cerr << "Debug messages..." << endl;


    // the location of the next window Batman should jump to.
    cout << X0 <<  Y0 << endl;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Standard Output Stream: 00 Game information: Failure: invalid input.
>   Expected 'x y' but found '00'

Мой вопрос: что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Кто выдает это сообщение? Это ошибка компиляции, это ошибка выполнения , или это сообщение выдает сама программа? В каком предложении возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: Гадание на хрустальном шаре показывает, что надо добавить пробел между выводимыми значениями.
    // the location of the next window Batman should jump to.
    cout << X0 << " " <<  Y0 << endl;
Но к идее "научитесь формулировать вопросы" всячески присоединяюсь.